# DOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: magento2

I am using project from another computer. So I copied my project and got this error. where to change what to get rid of this error . When i try to access `http://localhost/sitespi`  screen appear with this logs

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user
>   'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in
>   /var/www/html/sitespi/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php:128
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /var/www/html/sitespi/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(128):
>   PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'root', 'dev', Array) #1
>   /var/www/html/sitespi/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(111):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect() #2
>   /var/www/html/sitespi/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(353):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect() #3
>   /var/www/html/sitespi/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(460):
>   Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->_connect() #4
>   /var/www/html/sitespi/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array) #5
>   /var/www/html/sitespi/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(465):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT`main_ta...', Array) #6
>   /var/www/html/sitespi/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(520):
>   Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->_query('SELECT `main_ta...',
>   Array) #7
>   /var/www/html/sitespi/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(737):
>   Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->query(Object(Magento\Framework\DB\Select),
>   Array) #8
>   /var/www/html/sitespi/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection/Db/FetchStrategy/Query.php(21):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchAll(Object(Magento\Framework\DB\Select),
>   Array) #9
>   /var/www/html/sitespi/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection/AbstractDb.php(772):
>   Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategy\Query->fetchAll(Object(Magento\Framework\DB\Select),
>   Array) #10
>   /var/www/html/sitespi/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection/AbstractDb.php(668):
>   Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb->_fetchAll(Object(Magento\Framework\DB\Select))
>
> ## 11 /var/www/html/sitespi/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection/AbstractDb.php(572):
>
> Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb->getData() #12
>   /var/www/html/sitespi/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection/AbstractDb.php(557):
>   Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb->loadWithFilter(false,
>   false) #13
>   /var/www/html/sitespi/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection.php(820):
>   Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb->load() #14
>   /var/www/html/sitespi/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Source/RuntimeConfigSource.php(78):
>   Magento\Framework\Data\Collection->getIterator() #15
>   /var/www/html/sitespi/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Source/RuntimeConfigSource.php(58):
>   Magento\Config\App\Config\Source\RuntimeConfigSource->loadConfig() #16
>   /var/www/html/sitespi/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config/ConfigSourceAggregated.php(40):
>   Magento\Config\App\Config\Source\RuntimeConfigSource->get('') #17
>   /var/www/html/sitespi/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Type/System/Reader.php(73):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Config\ConfigSourceAggregated->get() #18
>   /var/www/html/sitespi/var/generation/Magento/Config/App/Config/Type/System/Reader/Proxy.php(95):
>   Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System\Reader->read() #19
>   /var/www/html/sitespi/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Type/System.php(212):
>   Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System\Reader\Proxy->read() #20
>   /var/www/html/sitespi/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Type/System.php(170):
>   Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System->loadDefaultScopeData('default')
>
> ## 21 /var/www/html/sitespi/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config.php(139):
>
> Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System->get('default/web/sec...') #22
>   /var/www/html/sitespi/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config.php(90):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Config->get('system', 'default/web/sec...') #23
>   /var/www/html/sitespi/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config.php(103):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Config->getValue('web/secure/use_...',
>   'default', NULL) #24
>   /var/www/html/sitespi/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/HeaderProvider/Hsts.php(48):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Config->isSetFlag('web/secure/use_...') #25
>   /var/www/html/sitespi/vendor/magento/framework/App/Response/HeaderManager.php(41):
>   Magento\Store\Model\HeaderProvider\Hsts->canApply() #26
>   /var/www/html/sitespi/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(123):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Response\HeaderManager->beforeSendResponse(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
>
> ## 27 /var/www/html/sitespi/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/Response/Http/Interceptor.php(26):
>
> Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor->___callPlugins('sendResponse',
>   Array, Array) #28
>   /var/www/html/sitespi/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(185):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor->sendResponse() #29
>   /var/www/html/sitespi/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(156):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Http->handleDeveloperMode(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap),
>   Object(Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception)) #30
>   /var/www/html/sitespi/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(263):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Http->catchException(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap),
>   Object(Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception)) #31
>   /var/www/html/sitespi/index.php(39):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
>
> ## 32 {main} Next Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in
>
> /var/www/html/sitespi/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php:144
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /var/www/html/sitespi/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(111):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect() #1
>   /var/www/html/sitespi/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(353):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect() #2
>   /var/www/html/sitespi/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(460):
>   Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->_connect() #3
>   /var/www/html/sitespi/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array) #4
>   /var/www/html/sitespi/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(465):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT`main_ta...', Array) #5
>   /var/www/html/sitespi/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(520):
>   Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->_query('SELECT `main_ta...',
>   Array) #6
>   /var/www/html/sitespi/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(737):
>   Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->query(Object(Magento\Framework\DB\Select),
>   Array) #7
>   /var/www/html/sitespi/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection/Db/FetchStrategy/Query.php(21):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchAll(Object(Magento\Framework\DB\Select),
>   Array) #8
>   /var/www/html/sitespi/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection/AbstractDb.php(772):
>   Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategy\Query->fetchAll(Object(Magento\Framework\DB\Select),
>   Array) #9
>   /var/www/html/sitespi/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection/AbstractDb.php(668):
>   Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb->_fetchAll(Object(Magento\Framework\DB\Select))
>
> ## 10 /var/www/html/sitespi/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection/AbstractDb.php(572):
>
> Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb->getData() #11
>   /var/www/html/sitespi/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection/AbstractDb.php(557):
>   Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb->loadWithFilter(false,
>   false) #12
>   /var/www/html/sitespi/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection.php(820):
>   Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb->load() #13
>   /var/www/html/sitespi/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Source/RuntimeConfigSource.php(78):
>   Magento\Framework\Data\Collection->getIterator() #14
>   /var/www/html/sitespi/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Source/RuntimeConfigSource.php(58):
>   Magento\Config\App\Config\Source\RuntimeConfigSource->loadConfig() #15
>   /var/www/html/sitespi/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config/ConfigSourceAggregated.php(40):
>   Magento\Config\App\Config\Source\RuntimeConfigSource->get('') #16
>   /var/www/html/sitespi/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Type/System/Reader.php(73):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Config\ConfigSourceAggregated->get() #17
>   /var/www/html/sitespi/var/generation/Magento/Config/App/Config/Type/System/Reader/Proxy.php(95):
>   Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System\Reader->read() #18
>   /var/www/html/sitespi/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Type/System.php(212):
>   Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System\Reader\Proxy->read() #19
>   /var/www/html/sitespi/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Type/System.php(170):
>   Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System->loadDefaultScopeData('default')
>
> ## 20 /var/www/html/sitespi/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config.php(139):
>
> Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System->get('default/web/sec...') #21
>   /var/www/html/sitespi/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config.php(90):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Config->get('system', 'default/web/sec...') #22
>   /var/www/html/sitespi/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config.php(103):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Config->getValue('web/secure/use_...',
>   'default', NULL) #23
>   /var/www/html/sitespi/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/HeaderProvider/Hsts.php(48):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Config->isSetFlag('web/secure/use_...') #24
>   /var/www/html/sitespi/vendor/magento/framework/App/Response/HeaderManager.php(41):
>   Magento\Store\Model\HeaderProvider\Hsts->canApply() #25
>   /var/www/html/sitespi/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(123):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Response\HeaderManager->beforeSendResponse(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
>
> ## 26 /var/www/html/sitespi/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/Response/Http/Interceptor.php(26):
>
> Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor->___callPlugins('sendResponse',
>   Array, Array) #27
>   /var/www/html/sitespi/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(185):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor->sendResponse() #28
>   /var/www/html/sitespi/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(156):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Http->handleDeveloperMode(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap),
>   Object(Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception)) #29
>   /var/www/html/sitespi/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(263):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Http->catchException(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap),
>   Object(Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception)) #30
>   /var/www/html/sitespi/index.php(39):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
>
> ## 31 {main}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After copy the files, you check to changes database connection at

> /var/www/html/sitespi/app/etc/env.php

```
 'db' => 
  array (
    'table_prefix' => '',
    'connection' => 
    array (
      'default' => 
      array (
        'host' => '[Yourhost]',
        'dbname' => '[DBName]',
        'username' => '[DbUser]',
        'password' => '[DbPassword]',
        'active' => '1',
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

**Then put the proper  mysql access at there**

*After that You should
Delete all clear cache by deleting files from*

- **/var/www/html/sitespi/var/cache**
- **/var/www/html/sitespi/var/page_cache**

**Also  if you have any cache  like redis ,memcache then flush it**.

***`Most import, you need to check your database user has enough User privilege for that database`***.